# AWS Cloudfront drops custom domain name and redirects to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk environment with CloudFront serving SSL (ASP.Net MVC). CloudFront has a custom domain name. Everything works fine until the user's session cookie expires or the user tries to access a secured area without logging in and is redirected to the login page. When either of these two things happens, the user is somehow redirected to the actual elastic beanstalk environment and it also drops SSL, so if the user doesn't notice they'll be sending their login credentials without SSL. For example, if the user accesses https://custom.domain.com/admin without being logged in they get redirected to http://aws.elasticbeanstalkcontainer.com, same for session expiration.  It worked fine on IIS10 before migrating to AWS. It seems that when EC2 sends the redirect back somehow CloudFront is missing it and not changing it to the custom domain name. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you IIS10 configuration does the redirects correctly by double checking how the configuration should change behind a proxy.

Answer (score 3):

It is not CloudFront's job to monitor for redirect responses coming from your server and rewrite them with a different domain name. That's not something it does. You have to configure your application running on Elastic Beanstalk to be aware of the correct domain name it should use when it sends redirect responses back to the client.

Comment: This is correct.  If the origin is correctly configured for it, then whitelisting the `Host` header in the CloudFront Cache Behavior settings may also remedy the issue.

Comment: @Mark B CloudFront is the proxy that rewrites the elastic beanstalk origin to the CloudFront domain or custom domain CName (in my case), including https to http for beanstalk since it only supports http. That's it's job. Everything works fine on in-house IIS10 servers w/SSL. I can't seem to find a way to hard-code the domain name in my .Net Identity app. I've tried URL rewrites but it breaks because beanstalk only supports http. I'm not very familiar with AWS, how did you get it working with your .Net MVC environment? Thanks.

Comment: @Sam.A. CloudfFront proxies the traffic **TO** the server. It returns to the client whatever the server responds with. It doesn't rewrite traffic coming from the server. It doesn't really "rewrite" anything (except maybe cache headers), it just forwards the request to the appropriate destination if it isn't in the cache. This is basic CDN stuff by the way, it's not specific to AWS or CloudFront. I'm not a .NET MVC developer, but I know this is the way it works in Java, Python, NodeJS and other environments, and I'm sure it's the same in .NET.